# Accessing state after it's set inside custom hook correctly with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks

This maybe isn't the right question. But I am having an issue with a custom form validation hook that doesn't read the input values when they are updated via a http request.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2pwrlj8ykn) if you wish to try it out.

This is the custom hook `useValidatedForm`

```
const [
    profileFormData,
    profileFormValidation,
    validateProfileForm,
    getProfileFormData
  ] = useValidatedForm(
    profileFormInitialState,
    profileFormValidationDefinitions
  );
```

I have state for the `profileFormInitialState`

```
const [profileFormInitialState, setProfileFormInitialState] = useState({
    firstName: ""
  });
```

I update this state in a http request (dummy http request at the moment)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fn = "first name";
    setProfileFormInitialState({
      firstName: fn
    });
    setContent({ title: "My Personal Details" });
    setLoading({ status: false });
  }, []);
```

This is my form which gets rendered to the DOM. The input value is set via the `profileFormInitialState` state.

```
const form = (
    <>
      <FormControl
        key={"profileForm"}
        submit={profileFormSubmit}
        form={profileFormData}
        validation={profileFormValidation}
      >
        <InputControl
          autoComplete="off"
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder={profileFormInitialState.firstName}
          value={profileFormInitialState.firstName}
          onInput={e =>
            setProfileFormInitialState({ firstName: e.target.value })
          }
          onChange={e => e.preventDefault()}
          label="First Name*"
          columns="2"
          position="left"
        >
          <ErrorMsg map="required" msg="First Name is required" />
        </InputControl>
        <InputButton
          modifier={"Button--profile"}
          disabled={!profileFormValidation.valid}
          buttonText="Update Profile"
          type="submit"
        />
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
```

Below is my `useValidatedForm` custom hook

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ValidaJS from "valida-js";

function stateFactory(fields) {
  return Object.keys(fields).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = {
      value: fields[key],
      meta: {
        touched: false,
        dirty: false
      }
    };
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function emptyErrorFactory(fields) {
  return Object.keys(fields).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = [];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function rulesByNameFactory(descriptors, validators) {
  const descriptorBy = descriptors.reduce((acc, descriptor) => {
    acc[descriptor.type] = acc[descriptor.type];
    acc[descriptor.name] = acc[descriptor.name]
      ? acc[descriptor.name].concat([descriptor])
      : [descriptor];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(descriptorBy).reduce(
    (acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = ValidaJS.rulesCreator(validators, descriptorBy[key]);
      return acc;
    },
    { default: ValidaJS.rulesCreator(validators, descriptors) }
  );
}

function getDataFromState(state) {
  return Object.keys(state).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = state[key].value;

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function extendsValidations(key, validation, newErrors = []) {
  const newValidation = {
    errors: {
      ...validation.errors,
      [key]: newErrors
    }
  };
  newValidation["valid"] = Object.keys(newValidation.errors).every(errorKey => {
    return newValidation.errors[errorKey].length === 0;
  });
  return newValidation;
}

function onChangeHandlerByKey(
  state,
  key,
  setState,
  setValidation,
  validation,
  rulesBy
) {
  return event => {
    const newState = {
      ...state,
      [key]: {
        ...state[key],
        value:
          event.currentTarget.type == "checkbox"
            ? event.currentTarget.checked
            : event.currentTarget.value,
        meta: {
          ...state[key].meta,
          dirty: true
        }
      }
    };
    const newErrors = ValidaJS.validate(
      rulesBy[key],
      getDataFromState(newState)
    ).errors[key];
    setState(newState);
    setValidation(extendsValidations(key, validation, newErrors));
  };
}

function onClickHandlerByKey(state, key, setState) {
  return _ => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [key]: {
        ...state[key],
        meta: {
          ...state[key].meta,
          touched: true
        }
      }
    });
  };
}

function formDataFactory(state, setState, setValidation, validation, rulesBy) {
  return Object.keys(state).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = {
      meta: state[key].meta,
      input: {
        value: state[key].value,
        onClick: onClickHandlerByKey(
          state,
          key,
          setState,
          setValidation,
          validation,
          rulesBy
        ),
        onChange: onChangeHandlerByKey(
          state,
          key,
          setState,
          setValidation,
          validation,
          rulesBy
        )
      }
    };
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const useValidatedForm = (
  fields = {},
  descriptors = [],
  validators = ValidaJS.validators
) => {
  const initialErrorsObj = emptyErrorFactory(fields);
  const initialState = stateFactory(fields);
  console.log("initial state = " + initialState.firstName.value);
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  console.log("state = " + state.firstName.value);
  const [validation, setValidation] = useState({
    valid: true,
    errors: initialErrorsObj
  });
  const rulesBy = rulesByNameFactory(descriptors, validators);
  const form = formDataFactory(
    state,
    setState,
    setValidation,
    validation,
    rulesBy
  );

  const getData = () => getDataFromState(state);
  const setData = data => setState(stateFactory(data));
  const validate = () => {
    const newValidations = ValidaJS.validate(
      rulesBy.default,
      getDataFromState(state)
    );
    setValidation({
      ...newValidations,
      errors: { ...initialErrorsObj, ...newValidations.errors }
    });
    return newValidations.valid;
  };

  return [form, validation, validate, getData, setData];
};

export default useValidatedForm;
```

In the `useValidatedForm` function, the issue that I am having is that when I submit the form and this function is called, `initialState` is correct, it returns `first name`, it is used as the initial value for `state` but `state` will return as an empty string and will do so until I type in the input and then it updates correctly. So I'm not exactly sure how to make this validation work as it relys on the `state` value and updating the `state` value with `setState`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging your code, you have really to go step by step:

- Start from where it is faulty -> validateProfileForm -> where does it come from ?
- validate returned by your hook -> where does validate gets its data from ?
- the upper scope state variable -> where does it come from ?
- useState line 147 in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/91n3yjp56y) -> where does useState gets it value from ?
- initialState -> has initialState the right value ?
- Yes -> why doesn't useState use initialState ?
- Oh wait, useState uses the initialParameters ONLY the first call, so I cannot use the parameter to re-initialize the values. Because you set the initialState afterward, the first value useState had is now stuck in state unless you use setState

So now, your options are, use setState only when initialState changes, (because if you do it every time you will be stuck with the initial values), but because your stateFactory always returns a new object, I don't recommand that (you would have to compare deeply)

OR

Provide an imperative method to re-initialize the state, this way you don't have to deal with a possibly annoying diffing system.

Also, the reason why you even get "first name" in the input in the first place, is because you set it's value with `value={profileFormInitialState.firstName}`, when your form should be the one handling that for you.